# Getting content that are not wrapped in tags

Tags: javascript, html

Here's what I'm dealing with; I don't have control of it.

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div>etc.</div>
  <div>etc.</div>
  (foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)
  <ul>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
  </ul>
  (foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)
  <div>etc.</div>
</div>
```

How can I get `(foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)` out of `#foo`?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make much sense. The anchor tags *are* wrapped in tags.

Comment: @Spectric The HTML doesn't make any sense right from the beginning. I have reported to the ones who are in charges, but while waiting, and in the case of being ignored, I think this worth a try.

Comment: I suppose it is. There are two occurrences of the expected output in the HTML. Would you like to return both?

Comment: @Spectric They are effectively the same, so one or two simply doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than I thought: Remove all children that are not `a`, the rest is trivial.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $foo = $('#foo').clone();

  $foo.find('*').not('a').remove();
  $foo.html($foo.html().trim().replace(/(.+)\s*\1/, '$1'));
  
  $('#foo').remove();
  $foo.appendTo('#content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="foo">
    <div>etc.</div>
    <div>etc.</div>
    (foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)
    <ul>
      <li>etc.</li>
      <li>etc.</li>
      <li>etc.</li>
      <li>etc.</li>
    </ul>
    (foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)
    <div>etc.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex that is designed to match anything within brackets to extract the non-wrapped tags:

```js
const targetElement = document.getElementById("foo")
const result = targetElement.innerHTML.match(/(\(.+\))/gm)
console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div>etc.</div>
  <div>etc.</div>
  (foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)
  <ul>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
  </ul>
  (foobar) (<a href="example.com">barfoo</a>) | (<a href="stackoverflow.com">lorem</a>) (ipsum)
  <div>etc.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will likely catch false positives as the `etc.` may contain text that also match the regex.